# Is there any way to assign a laravel resource inside another resource?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

> Users resource

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'=>$this->id,
            'name'=>$this->name,
            'email'=>$this->email,
            'phone'=>$this->phone,
            'address'=> addressResource::collection($this->address)
        ];
    }
```

> Address resource

```
    public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id'=>$this->id,
        'user_id'=>$this->user_id,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'address'=>$this->address,
        'municipality'=>$this->municipality
];
}
```

> User return

```
$id = auth()->user()->id;
return new UserResource(User::findOrFail($id));
```

Im returning from a addresses controller a user Resource that contains all of the information of the user and the addreses resources that are registered with the user_id, Im trying to do it as shown in the laravel docs but it doesent seems to work for me any idea how to do it?

Comment: return new UserResource(User::all());

Comment: can you show to us the response ?